# Seven people are interviewed for a possible promotion. In how many orders can the seven candidates be interviewed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Seven people are interviewed for a possible promotion. In how many orders can the
seven candidates be interviewed?

I know the answer is 5040 but don't know how to get to it.

Comment: The multiplication principle states that to find the number of ways a scenario can be accomplished and the scenario can be broken into different steps where regardless of which choice, the *number* of choices available to the other steps do not change (even if the choices themselves change), the total number of ways to complete the entire scenario is the multiplication of the number of ways to complete each step individually.  Break this into steps: pick the first person, pick the second person, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: How many possibilities are there for the first interview? The second? Third? Etc.

Answer (score -1):

The requires input into your scientific calculator.

7!= 5040

Comment: But *WHY* is the answer $7!$?